# How to multiply a voltage when its lower than 5V?

Tags: voltage, switches, buck-boost

I am working with a power source of a range from 0-20V and I need to regulate the voltage to 12V. I plan to use a buck boost converter to stabilize the voltage, the problem is the input range is 5-32V. I need the power to not be lost when it's generating less than 5V.

What I am thinking of is multiplying the voltage if it is less than 5V but I don't know how to do that. I have looked into MOSFET switches but I don't understand how those work.

Comment: You're not going to get any power out of your source when the voltage is 0 V. So please give us a usable spec. What is the minimum voltage you need to accept as an input? And how much power do you need to deliver at 12 V?

Comment: The minimum voltage can be 1V. The goal is to produce the most power, the max amperage produced is about 620mA. There is no value for power needed to be reached, its just whats the highest that can be reached. This is the [buck-boost](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00JKG57T4/ref=twister_B017LX7X3U?_encoding=UTF8&th=1) being used.

Comment: @Jon You can't get there from here. First off, the buck boost has a minimum spec that doesn't meet your 1 V spec. This means you'd need yet another boost (conditionally used, which means more circuitry) to move lower input voltages, with power too, up to the range your buck boost needs. This isn't necessarily impossible. Pretty much anything is possible given enough time and money. But it is enough to say you should find other approaches to whatever problem you have. Which, by the way, means you should definitely WRITE A LOT MORE about. Perhaps someone could offer a novel/useful thought, then.

Comment: You should find lots of boost converters able to work from 1.0 V or less , designed to be powered from batteries (although getting more than 6 W from parallel cells may not be common). I'd ditch the part you chose and start a new product search for a converter that meets your needs.

Comment: What is the power source?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get 620 mA @ 12 V as an end result ...that means approximately 7.5 W

At 1 V input and assuming ~80 % efficiency you need to supply 9.5 A from your source.
Not an impossible scenario but quite a challenge.

Re-visit your specs and work out exactly what you can provide from your source and you'll be able to figure out what can be done in the convertor and what power you might deliver.